# Change character sequence

Tags: pwm, code-optimization, keyboard

I turn on the transmission of one key that works to open the door, but after a certain time I need to close the door, and for this I need to use the second key. I want to do without additional buttons, so it is required to emit key 1 when power is applied, and after 20 seconds, for example, switch and emit key 2. What is the most simple and correct way to do this?
Apply a timer or emit key 1, for example 1000 times, and after overflow 1000, start emitting key 2.

This sketch only constantly sends the first key to the digital pin, without switching to the second.
You need to figure out how you can switch to the second key.

```
const int KEY_LEN = 54; //Number of characters in the key
const char key1[KEY_LEN] = {"SSSSSS001101001001110001000000000000000000000011001010"}; // Open
const char key2[KEY_LEN] = {"SSSSSS001010111010000000000001000000000000010000000000"}; // Close

int Preamble = 1000; // Preamble duration in microseconds
int zero= 200; // Duration of zero in microseconds
int One= 440; // Duration of a unit in microseconds

const int LED_PIN = 13; // Used digital pin 13 of the arduino to connect the transmitter
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

    for (int n = 0; n < KEY_LEN; n++)
    {
      if (key1[n] == '1') //execute if bit value == 1
      {
        sendSignal(One);
      }

      else if (key1[n] == '0')//execute if bit value == 0
      {
        sendSignal(zero);
      }
      else
      {
        sendSignal(Preamble); // Стартовый импульс
      }

    }
  }

void sendSignal(int duration)
{
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually recommend against using `delay()`s, but if this system will only ever have to do what you've described, using `delay()`s is the simplest way to implement it.

I would suggest sending key-1, possibly several times, maybe a half second apart, delay for the 20 seconds you suggested, then send key-2, *definitely* several times for security.